# How to switch from strongswan to openswan

Tags: raspberry-pi, strongswan

Having installed strongswan on my raspberry pi I want to switch to openswan but it is not working

built openswan and tried sudo make install but it is failing

Comment: answering my own question for others - get rid of the /etc/ipsec.* files before doing the make install - there is a note in the README that says it will not overwrite existing ipsec config files - this is to allow upgrading versions of openswan but when you are switching from strongswan to openswan you need the install to create new files

Comment: You're welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).